# How to display a choice between two ComboBox?

Tags: website-design, choices

I search an intuitive way to display a choice between two options with a specific ComboBox for each option.

The target is to display a roadmap by a specific axis of analysis ('Department' or 'Business Domain') defined by the user. That's why I thought about the radiobuttons. 
And then, the user has to select a specific value in a combobox (or something else) for this specific axe.

I thought about the following mockup:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk097O.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Or maybe a navigation by "tab", with a ComboBox per tab:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVPdKh.png)</sup>

But the content is really similar for each tab.

I can't directly ask the users now and the feature is a bit "urgent" but I'd like to offer something with a nice UX.

Do you have a suggestion for this kind of user choice/selection?

Comment: Tabs definitely are not the best way to convey decision making is needed. They are the mean to break information on several related areas.

Answer (score 2):

Disable the non-active combobox. Leave it visible, but grayed out, so that only the selected one is interactive.

But can I ask why it's split into radio buttons with comboboxes? What kind of options is the user actually picking here?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, they have to choice between two main kind of analyses "Department" and "Business Domain" and select a specific value in the list. I'm updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX4fSL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The reason why a tabular view is not recommended is because the user will not be able to see all of the data at once, allowing him/her to compare what's offered. Just make sure it's quite obvious what is selected and what isn't. Also keep an eye on hierarchy.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Without know what the options are it's harder to say if these solutions will work, so hope fully this works in your context.

I'd maybe break this up in to two steps, you choose the your first option, then your second.

[image]

But the mix of radio, then select boxes seems strange (again unsure of the content), so maybe something like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The both wireframe fit the needs. I updated my question with more information about the Options. I don't know if using a combobox for two values only is OK for users. It's one more click/action for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type of switch control to let user choose option. Switching to the different option will change the list below. Highlighted part is a good header for the list, too:
[image]